# Why Fedora 31 Live crashes when booted from some USB sticks but not when booted from others

Tags: fedora, boot, live-usb, crash

I'm planning to install Fedora 31 Workstation on my PC, but since I'm running an NVIDIA GPU and have experienced problems with other Linux distros (Ubuntu, Mint) I decided to give it a test run in live mode.

---

Now, the problem is that after Gnome Desktop Manager is up and running, the whole boot process freezes and one of two things happen, depending on the USB stick I use:

1. The screen goes black - occasionally I am able to enable another tty (via ctrl+alt+FX), but most of the time it just stays unresponsive.
2. It hangs for about 3 minutes and then displays a bunch of error messages, some of them being:

> mount: /oldsys/sys: special device /oldroot/sys does not exist.
>
> mount: /oldsys/proc: special device /oldroot/proc does not exist.
>
> dracut Warning: Killing all remaining processes.
>
> Powering off.

Needless to say the PC powers off after that.

---

Don't get me wrong, I'm used to having problems with Linux setup process due to my GPU, but what really bugs me is **why is it all so different depending on the USB stick I choose**.

I've tested 4 flash drives, tried burning the ISO with both the officially supported Fedora Media Writer and with dd from the command line, but it changed nothing. In 3 cases the PC powers off -- only one live session remains somewhat responsive.

I am really a newbie when it comes to hardware and hardware/software interaction, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: There are many potential reasons, including, but no limited to, how the USB stick maps logical sectors and what are the logical sector sizes, and how well the OS/Kernel/Device drivers map/translate this information--if they even can (some USB sicks may not give the information needed to do so, or give incorrect information). If tthe sticks are identical (same Mfg, same size, etc), that would suggest faulty/flaky USB hardware. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Broken/flaky USB stick?

(I've got some that work fine on some machines, and aren't even acknowledged by others. Never bothered to find out why.)